# Need help to get this Tradingview strategy from V2 to V5

Tags: pine-script

I'm attempting to convert my script from v2 to v5 strategy and add Buy Sell Alerts for webhook trading on MT5 via Pineconnector. This script is working fine in v2, and I am able to see Buy/Sell Signals at screen, but also want alerts to pop up if any Buy/Sell signal appears to trigger Pineconnector.

Following is my script:

`

```
`//@version=2
strategy(title='Sniper & Strategy by CSBender_', shorttitle='Sniper & Strategy by CSBender_', overlay=true, pyramiding=0, initial_capital=2000, currency=currency.USD)
//============ signal Generator ==================================//
Period=input('720')//630
ch1 = security(tickerid, Period, open)
ch2 = security(tickerid, Period, close)
longCondition = crossover(ch2,ch1)
shortCondition = crossunder(ch2,ch1)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry(".", strategy.long)
plotshape(longCondition, style=shape.labelup, color=lime, text="Buy", textcolor=black, location=location.belowbar)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry(".", strategy.short)
plotshape(shortCondition, style=shape.labeldown, color=red, text="Sell", textcolor=black)
//============ Directional Projection ==================================//
channel3=input(false, title="Connect Projection High/Low")
tf2 = input('1', title="Trend Projection TF / Mins/D/W")
M2 = input('ATR')
P2 = input(13.00, type=float)
W2 = input(1)
pf2 = pointfigure(tickerid, 'close', M2, P2, W2)
spfc2 = security(pf2, tf2, close)
p22=plot(channel3?spfc2:spfc2==nz(spfc2[1])?spfc2:na, color=blue, linewidth=2, style=linebr, title="Projection", offset=0)
//====================colour bar======================
mysignal = ema(close, 13) - ema(close, 26)
barcolor(mysignal[0] > mysignal[1] ? green : red)
//============ Trend colour ema 1 y 2 ==================================//
src0 = close, len0 = input(13, minval=1, title="EMA 1")
ema0 = ema(src0, len0)
direction = rising(ema0, 2) ? +1 : falling(ema0, 2) ? -1 : 0
plot_color = direction > 0  ? lime: direction < 0 ? red : na
plot(ema0, title="EMA", style=line, linewidth=2, color = plot_color)
//============ ema 2 ==================================//
src02 = close, len02 = input(21, minval=1, title="EMA 2")
ema02 = ema(src02, len02)
direction2 = rising(ema02, 2) ? +1 : falling(ema02, 2) ? -1 : 0
plot_color2 = direction2 > 0  ? lime: direction2 < 0 ? red : na
plot(ema02, title="EMA Signal 2", style=line, linewidth=2, color = plot_color2)
//=============Hull MA ==================================//
show_hma = input(false, title="Display Hull MA Set:")
hma_src = input(close, title="Hull MA's Source:")
hma_base_length = input(8, minval=1, title="Hull MA's Base Length:")
hma_length_scalar = input(5, minval=0, title="Hull MA's Length Scalar:")
hullma(src, length)=>wma(2*wma(src, length/2)-wma(src, length), round(sqrt(length)))
plot(not show_hma ? na : hullma(hma_src, hma_base_length+hma_length_scalar*6), color=black, linewidth=2, title="Hull MA")
//============ Supertrend Generator ==================================//
Factor=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 000, title="Trend Transition Signal")
Pd=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))
TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],0)
plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=1000, minheight=50, transp=85)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=1000, minheight=50, transp=85)
//============ Trend Generator ==================================//
slow = 8
fast = 5
vh1 = ema(highest(avg(low, close), fast), 5)
vl1 = ema(lowest(avg(high, close), slow), 8)
e_ema1 = ema(close, 1)
e_ema2 = ema(e_ema1, 1)
e_ema3 = ema(e_ema2, 1)
tema = 1 * (e_ema1 - e_ema2) + e_ema3
e_e1 = ema(close, 8)
e_e2 = ema(e_e1, 5)
dema = 2 * e_e1 - e_e2
signal = tema > dema ? max(vh1, vl1) : min(vh1, vl1)
is_call = tema > dema and signal > low and (signal-signal[1] > signal[1]-signal[2])
is_put = tema < dema and signal < high and (signal[1]-signal > signal[2]-signal[1])
plotshape(is_call ? 1 : na, title="BUY ARROW", color=green, text="B", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(is_put ? -1 : na, title="SELL ARROW", color=red, text="S", style=shape.arrowdown)
//============ END ==================================//`
```

Am SUPER new to pinescript but need to be able to add in the strategy alerts available in V5
I started understanding the V4 differences to add in .int to input variables and.ta to technical indicators but got WAY too many other errors I don't understand.  Thanks in advance to the smarter than I folks here!

Comment: What is your question? What is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Can someone explain the script? I don't even understand the long and short condition.

```
ch1 = security(tickerid, Period, open)
ch2 = security(tickerid, Period, close)
```

Thats the only used function for short and long condition with crossover and crossunder?? I don't get it.